# Программа для вывода гистограммы длин слов во входном потоке

Tags: c, потоки-данных

Читаю сейчас K&R.Возникли трудности с задачей 1.13. Она звучит так: "Напишите программу для вывода гистограммы длин слов во входном потоке."

Как заполнить массив длинами слов я знаю.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define in 1
#define out 0

main(){
    char dig[15];
    int c,m,i,j,state,st,cn;
    state = out;
    cn = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        dig[i] = 0;
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n'){
            state = out;
            ++dig[cn];
            cn = 0;
        }else if (state == out){
            state = in;
            ++cn;   
        }
    }

}
```

Натолкните на алгоритм вывода гистограммы.Заранее спасибо.

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++){
        if(dig[i] != 0){
        printf("Слов с %d буквой(ами) :",i);
            for ( j = 1 ; j <= dig[i] ; j++){
                printf("+");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Только теперь он на последнее слово внимания не обращает.

Comment: Что-то в духе

      for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < dig[i]; j++)
          putchar('X');
        puts("");
      }

это не она?

Иногда код короче толкований на естественном языке.

Comment: На последнее слово не обращает внимание, потому что не встречает символов `' '`, `'\t'` или `'\n'` в конце ввода. Автомат так и остаётся в состоянии in. Нужно после цикла {while} еще дописать {++dig[cn];}